# Limit of closed set with lower boundary $a_k$ converging to $a$ but $a_k$ > a is open.

Tags: general-topology, limits, elementary-set-theory

I am unsure about the following result which I need for a proof.

> Let $(a_k) \in \mathbb R$ be a sequence such that $a_k \ge a_{k+1}$ and  $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = a$ and $a_k > a$ for all $k$. Then the closed set $[a_k, b]$ converges to the half open set $(a, b]$.

My reasoning is that since no interval $[a_k, b]$ contains $a$, their union cannot contain $a$ either. Therefore $$a\notin \lim_{k\to\infty} [a_k,b]$$

Comment: What does it mean for a set to converge to another set? In other words, how is $\lim_{k\to\infty}[a_k, b]$ defined?

Comment: So far, so good. Now you need to give an argument that $(a,b]$ is covered.